# Is there a way to place div elements side by side

Tags: html

Below are the div elements I am trying to place it side by side. Is it possible?

```html
<div style="padding-left:10px">
  <h4 class="line">{sev_pas}</h4>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:10px">
  <div>sdfds</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can by using `display: inline-block` property. Just make sure what you are doing

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:10px">
  <h4 class="line">{sev_pas}</h4>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:10px">
  <div>sdfds</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE CSS CAN HELP :

```css
div{
width : 150px;
height: 150px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style='background: red'></div>
<div style='background: blue'></div>
<div style='background: orange'></div>
<div style='background: green'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: inline-block;`

```css
.first-div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.second-div{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div" style = "padding-left:10px">
  <h4 class ="line" >ok</h4>
</div>

<div class="second-div" style= "padding-left:10px"> sdfds</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using text in div element it's not best practice! it's better to put your text in `p` or `span` tag.

also you can use `"display:flex"` for div element so it's better to write something like below code:

```css
.container{
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
gap: 10px;
align-item:center;
}

.line{
margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h4 class ="line" >{sev_pas}</h4>
<span>sdfds</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block`  for set `div` or any other elements.

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
}

h2{
  background:orange;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:10px">
  <h2>DIV 2</h2>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:10px">
  <h2>DIV 1</h2>
</div>
```

Else there are also other methods like using `display: flex` or `display: grid` etc.